# How to change CSS in Jekyll for code snippets in specific language

Tags: css, markdown, jekyll

I use Jekyll for my blog and I'd like to change the background colour for Python code snippets:

````
```python
def foo():
    pass
```
````

I found that the background can be changed in `_sass/_code.css`:

```
pre {
    padding: 1.125em;
    background-color: $pre-background-color;
}
```

However, this affects all kinds of snippets. Is there a way to use a different setting for a specific language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each language will have its own class, in this case `language-python`.

To customize python source code you can set the css with that class for each token of the highlighter, for example to customize the `function` token and `Punctuation`:

```
.language-python .nf{
    background-color:red;
    color:green;
}
.language-python .p{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

That code will give us:

[image]

You can see all Rouge tokens at https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-tokens .